# How to retrieve the values of required keys in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash with keys and values.  How can I retrieve the values of the desired keys?

```
%a = qw(genea brain geneb heart genec kidney gened eye);
```

Now I want to retrieve the value for the keys `genec` and `gened`. How can I do this?

Comment: Please [consult the manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Variable-names)

Comment: Besides data access described above, you should probably read the perlfunc discussion of defined, for what happens when the keys don't exist in the hash. The suggestion to read Learning Perl is a good one, and will help you immensely I think.

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of the values for many keys at once, use a hash slice:

```
@lots_of_values = @hash{ @lots_of_keys };
```

Because a list is the result, you use the `@` sigil even though it is a hash; the values will be the order of the keys specified, including undef values where the specified keys don't exist in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you're asking is how to access elements of a hash.  As Quentin indicates, this is trivially google-able.

The [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) doc covers basic questions, and [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Data%3a-Hashes-%28Associative-Arrays%29) covers many other hash questions.

That said, to answer your question:

```
print $a{'genec'};
print $a{'gened'};
```

I also would not declare your hash in that way, as it's unclear what is a key and what is a value.  Instead, consider:

```
my %a = ('genea' => 'brain', 'geneb' => 'heart'); # etc.
```

Comment: You make a fair point about how to write the assignment, but there's no reason to quote these keys as written. While it can be argued that the OP's assignment was less readable, the % sigil in the front tells me all I need to know about the assignment and OP's method save a lot of typing without sacrificing too much readability.

Comment: There are several reasons to quote the key: to be consistent with those cases where quotes *are* required, to provide a visual distinction between constant strings and other things (both in the plain text code and as styled by a colorizing text editor), and to protect against erroneously leaving the quotes off in cases where they are required

Comment: But hin OPS case, '%a = qw(' - you read 8 characters and you you that the line is declaring a hash and initializing it from an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $GENEC = $a{genec};
 $GENED = $a{gened};
```

Please get yourself a copy of Learning Perl. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: BUT, I HAVE THE HASH WITH 20,000 ELEMENTS AND I HAVE TO RETRIEVE THE VALUE OF 5000 KEYS. How it is possible by this Answer?

Comment: You should edit your question, because that's not what you asked.  How do you know which 5000 hash entries you want?

Comment: I have the hash, which consists 2000 keys with values. I also have the 5000 keys (these 5000 are present in that 2000), i have to print the values of those 5000 keys

Comment: so you loop over the list of the keys you want, and use them to look up the values in the big hash.

Comment: user1541213: We have given you all the information needed for you to learn how to do this.  Your question boils down to "how do I access an individual element in a hash?" which has been answered.  Please look at some perl FAQs and do some googling if you don't understand how to access hash elements in perl, or do a for loop with an array of keys.

Comment: `print join ', ', @a{@five_thousand_keys};`  (It's a hash slice.)